# gulp-replace creating an unwanted directory

Tags: gulp, gulp-replace

I created this simple gulp task:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  gulp.src(['test.txt'])
    .pipe(replace('aaa', 'bbb'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('result.txt'))
})
```

The `test.txt` source file stands in the same directory as the gulpfile.

The problem is that it's creating the resulting file in `result.txt/test.txt`.

How can I make it create this `config.js` file without this unwanted `result.txt/` folder?

Comment: `gulp.dest('public/')` should work, no?

Comment: @Louis No, it says: `illegal operation on a directory`.

Comment: Well, I essentially reproduced what you are doing in your code and included the fix I suggested, and it works here. Please edit your question to make it a [mcve]. Show everything you tried and add the exact errors or results you are getting.

Comment: @Louis I just edited my question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the documentation, [`gulp.dest`](https://gulp.readme.io/docs/gulpdestpath-options) takes a target directory, not a filename.

If you want to put in the same directory as your `gulpfile.js`, then use `.`:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  gulp.src(['test.txt'])
    .pipe(replace('aaa', 'bbb'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
});
```

But **beware** as that will overwrite the original file! You can't rename a file with `gulp.dest`, for that you'll need to use another package, such as [`gulp-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) and doing something like this:

```
gulp.task('default', function () {
  gulp.src(['test.txt'])
    .pipe(replace('aaa', 'bbb'))
    .pipe(rename('target.txt'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.'))
});
```